# Need to unhide specific div from select .change

Tags: jquery

Im trying to only show the div with the same number.
The number is the id from the database so I can put it anywhere.
This also only works from the first select.
I need to pass the id number to jQuery so I can pass it to the unhide the div-XXX.
I just don't know how to do that.

http://jsfiddle.net/TacoFiesta/5wge2L2e/4/

the html

```
Status:
<select name="Status-335" id="changeStatus">
  <option>Polishing</option>
  <option>Photos</option>
  <option>Done</option>
</select>
<div class="photosNeededCheck" id="div-335" style="display:none;">...335...<br></div>

Status:
<select name="Status-360" id="changeStatus">
  <option>Polishing</option>
  <option>Photos</option>
  <option>Done</option>
</select>
<div class="photosNeededCheck" id="div-360" style="display:none;">...360...<br></div>
```

And the jQuery

```
$("#changeStatus").change(function () {
    // hide all optional elements
    $('.photosNeededCheck').css('display','none');

$("#changeStatus option:selected").each(function () {
    if($(this).val() == "Photos") {
        $('.photosNeededCheck').css('display','');
    } 
});
});
```

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change the id on your select to be a class of 'changeStatus', then alter your jQuery to use that class on the change event.  Then get out the id from the name attribute and alter the visibility of the div for each specific select.

```
$(".changeStatus").change(function () {
    // hide all optional elements
    var select = this;
    $('.photosNeededCheck').css('display', 'none');

    $("option:selected",select).each(function () {
        if ($(this).val() == "Photos") {
            var id = $(select).attr('name').split('-')[1];
            $('#div-'+id).css('display', '');
        }
    });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You can not use the same ID on different DOM elements.  Use a CLASS instead.

Class="changeStatus"

And your jquery

$('.changeStatus').change(function(){…your code here…});